# How to configure the default port for a dotnet MVC application?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am working on a very basic asp.net core web application.

When I run the application manually on my personal computer, the port is 5050.

I have written a Dockerfile (inspired from a tutorial). Here it is:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["projet1.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./projet1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "projet1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "projet1.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projet1.dll"]
```

When I run the image, the application is answering on port 80. This is a good thing, but I want to understand why it is listening on port 80.

I have no configuration file or no command line argument which says to my app to listen on port 80. How is this difference possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [documented](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/) in the overview for the runtime image you're using (right at the bottom):

> This image sets the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable to `http://+:80` which means that if you have not explicity [sic] set a URL in your application, via `app.UseUrl` in your Program.cs for example, then your application will be listening on port 80 inside the container.

When running the application locally, it *defaults* to using ports `5000` (HTTP) and `5001` (HTTPS). This can be overridden in `launchSettings.json`, which I expect you have done in order for it to use `5050` in your environment.

---

Note that the images you're using have been deprecated in favour of Microsoft's self-hosted [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/) and [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-sdk/) images.

Comment: thanks a lot. by the way, what are the differences between WORKDIR "/src/."  and WORKDIR "/src" ?

Comment: I don't think there *is* a difference.